# regex extract exact(not included) URL param value

Tags: regex

URLs might be

```
example.com/test?pid=123

example.com/test?test=ttt&pid=123

example.com/test#test=ttt&pid=123

example.com/test?pid=123&test=ttt&

example.com/test?xxxpid=123&test=ttt& //should not select because it has xxx prepanded.
```

it should only select pid parameter value. I have come up with

```
[^?]+(?:\?pid=([^&]+).*)?
```

but it is problematic.

```
example.com/test?gdsfg=sdfasdfa&pid=123
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> select **pid** parameter value

```
.+[?&]pid=([^=?&\s]+)
```

The needed value is in 1st captured group

https://regex101.com/r/E1yHVY/11

Comment: url.replace(regexARr[0],"----") returns only paramters, not whole URL. How can i return whole URL? Is it related to selection group?

Comment: @serkandemirel0420, but you have written *select pid parameter value*. The above pattern should match the whole url that contains `pid` param

Comment: yeah, did not know if should have stated that i need to use in replace function.

Comment: as basically example.com?pid=123 should be example.com?pid=---

Comment: @serkandemirel0420, are you making replacement in javascript?

Comment: I do, i just converted to .replace(/[?&]pid=([^=?&\s]+)/ig,"") , thanks for your help.